# PHP PDO Select Format AS Too few parameters

Tags: sql-server, select

I have the following code:

```
$extracting = $dbNew->query("SELECT *, Format(Date_Sheet, 'Short Date') AS modifiedDate FROM AccessDB WHERE modifiedDate LIKE '%2021%'");
```

Having the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: -3010 [Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

The problem is the "modifiedDate" because if I replace it with the "Date_Sheet" access field after the database table, I can run the query without issues.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `modifiedDate` is a calculated value, and it seems that the Access driver won't allow you to use it as a value in a comparison. I'd expect you to be able to extract the year directly from a Date column, so you should be able to do that with `Date_Sheet` directly.

Comment: This means that the syntax is correct and the issue is about the Access driver, my main issue is to compare the webpage date "YYYY-mm-dd" (this is how PHP is extracting it) against the AccessDB date "YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00" (this is how PHP is extracting it), I did test a lot of possible solutions with no luck, I need to check if both are equal. I will create a new question about it. Thank you for the very fast answer!!!